# Spread data table based on two columns, SQL server

Tags: sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql

I have a table I would like to re-shape, that currently looks like this:

```
ID    Year    Channel    Payments
 1    2012         HV         100
 1    2014         HV          56
 2    2012         NL       17000
 2    2012         HV         495
 3    2013         HV         565
```

etc... with many rows.

I need to re-shape the data so that there is one row per ID, and multiple columns showing the Payments in each Year and Channel. For example, the above table would look like this:

```
ID   HV2012   HV2013   HV2014   NL2012
 1      100     NULL       56     NULL
 2      495     NULL     NULL    17000
 3     NULL      565     NULL     NULL
```

I have been able to do this quite easily in the past using dplyr in R, but now need to use SQL server.  I haven't been able to find a way to do this without having to specify the names of each new column - as my data covers many Channels and Years this isn't really feasible. I understand it may require dynamic SQL, but I am not experienced at using this.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you feel you need to do that? It's not a very good design pattern, every year you'll have to add columns to your table (and remove old ones?). The table you have seems perfectly fine.

Comment: Honeybadger - I know it doesn't seem sensible, but it is definitely needed for downstream analysis that requires the data in this shape. Unfortunately, it would take too long to change all the subsequent analysis.

Comment: @rw2 I have updated answer to save result in a temporary table. Request you to accept if you find it useful and right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the similar query which will run in lower version of SQL Server also.

```
-- query
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Channel + Convert(Varchar(4) ,Year))
            FROM testTable c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Id, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select Id, Payments,
                Channel + Convert(Varchar(4) ,Year) NewCol
                from testTable
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(Payments)
                for NewCol in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

You can find the live demo [**here**](https://rextester.com/CXX71736).

**EDIT**

To save data in the temporary table you can try the following query.

```
create table MyTable
(
    Id int,
    Year int,
    Channel varchar(10),
    Payments int
)

insert into MyTable values 
               (1,2012,'HV',100),
               (1,2014,'HV',56),
               (2,2012,'NL',17000),
               (2,2012,'HV',495), 
               (3,2013,'HV',565)


Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '    
if object_id(''##TestTable'') is not null
begin
    drop table ##TestTable
end

create table ##TestTable([Id] int null, ' + 
            Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(Channel + CONVERT(Varchar(4), Year)) + ' Varchar(20) null'            
            From [dbo].MyTable
            Order By 1 
            For XML Path('')),1,1,'')+ ')
INSERT INTO ##TestTable
Select *
 From (
        Select A.ID, A.Payments
              ,B.*
         From  [dbo].MyTable a 
         Cross Apply ( values ( Channel + CONVERT(Varchar(4), Year)
                     )) B ([Value])
      ) S
 Pivot (sum([Payments]) For [Value] in 
 (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(Channel + CONVERT(Varchar(4), Year))                                                               
                                               From myTable
                                               Order By 1 
                                               For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'

--SELECT @SQL

Exec(@SQL)

SELECT * FROM ##TestTable
```

You can find the demo [**here**](https://rextester.com/CDR51840).

Comment: This is also great. As I asked an33sh - is there a way to save the outputs of this INTO another table?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dynamic pivot query to achieve this.

```
-- data

create table testTable
(
    Id int,
    Year int,
    Channel varchar(10),
    Payments int
)

 insert into testTable values (1,2012,'HV',100)
 insert into testTable values (1,2014,'HV',56)
 insert into testTable values (2,2012,'NL',17000)
 insert into testTable values (2,2012,'HV',495)
 insert into testTable values (3,2013,'HV',565)


-- query
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(c.Channel,c.Year))
            FROM testTable c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT Id, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select Id
                    , CONCAT(Channel,Year ) YC
                    , Payments
                from testTable
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(Payments)
                for YC in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: Thanks - this does just want I want. How would I go about saving the output into a table (e.g. one called #testTable2)? I tried putting an INTO statement above "from testTable" but got an incorrect syntax error.

Comment: @rw2, I hope you've already sorted out this with Suraj's answer.